# Form validation of html form data in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

How can I validate the input data from a form that created without using CodeIgniter's form ?

My form looks like this :

```html
<form method="POST" name="frmNewUser" action="<?php echo site_url('users/signup'); ?>" id="contact">
     <div class="lable">
          <div class="col_1_of_2 span_1_of_2"><input name="u_fname" type="text" class="text" value="First Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First Name';}" id="active"></div>
                <div class="col_1_of_2 span_1_of_2"><input name="u_lname" type="text" class="text" value="Last Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Last Name';}"></div>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
     </div>
     <div class="lable-2">
          <input name="u_email" type="text" class="text" value="your@email.com " onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'your@email.com ';}">
          <input name="u_pwd" type="password" class="text" value="Password " onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password ';}">
     </div>
     <h3>By creating an account, you agree to our <span class="term"><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></span></h3>
     <div class="submit">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" >
     </div>
     <div class="clear"> </div>
  </form>
```

And here is my controller :

```
function signup(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $u_fname = $this->input->post('u_fname');
        $u_lname = $this->input->post('u_lname');
        $u_email = $this->input->post('u_email');
        $u_pwd = $this->input->post('u_pwd');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules( $this->input->post('u_fname'), 'First Name', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            echo "error";
        }
    }
```

However the run() function of form_validation returns FALSE even though u_fname has input value.
How can I grab the data from the form with post method and validate the data using form_validation from CodeIgniter ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I just need to change

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules( $this->input->post('u_fname'), 'First Name', 'required');
```

to

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('u_fname', 'First Name', 'required');
```

previous one passed the value to the function meanwhile the new one passed the "name" of the object.